# Using raster calculator in QGIS gives solid black block when adding rasters together?

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator

I'm attempting to add a few raster layers together, but the result is a solid black rectangle. To simplify things I tried adding a '1' to one raster only.  Eg. for a raster layer callled prec9_23 I have the following formula:

`"prec9_23@1" + 1`

Even that gives a solid block, all with the same value.  What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to try to recalculate the statistical values of your data as you can see below:

For example, under Load Min/Max values, select Min/Max, then select Actual (slower) and full/current extent depending your data, then press Load.

After computing the Min/Max values of the pixels, click apply and see if the values were updated or not.

[image]

**Update**

There is nothing wrong in your data. Here is the output:

[image]

The sample raster image is your original image, and the Result raster (the one displayed) is the output after adding a value of 1.

I did not do anything exceptional, I stretched your data to Min/Max, Actual(solwer) as I explained earlier, then pressed Load. Then I used raster calculator to add value of 1 to the sample image:

```
"sample_raster@1"  +  1
```

Then saved the output image as Geotiff. I repeated the above steps again of stretching the Result image to Min/Max, Actual(solwer), and pressed Load again.

That's all what I did.

I used QGIS 2.14.5. Try to update your QGIS version if you are using an older version.

Comment: I assumed you meant to do this on the resultant raster layer.  I tried that and it's still a solid block of one value.

Comment: Can you share a small portion of your data to test it?

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/a/0ivca)
I saved a layer I was testing with as a Gtiff and uploaded to the link above.
</p>I tried adding the value 1 to the layer and then recalculating statistical values, and I also tried recalculating first and then doing the addition, with the same result.  Thanks

Comment: I tried to download your data but I couldn't find any link. Can I download the data or it is just for viewing?

Comment: Please try this link:  [link](http://www.mediafire.com/view/hlljb3wvl6gb8wt/sample_raster.tif)
</p>
As text: http://www.mediafire.com/view/hlljb3wvl6gb8wt/sample_raster.tif

Comment: Nothing wrong in your data. Please see the updated explanation.

Comment: I created a new project and tried again and it worked both with and without stretching first.  Maybe it was a qgis bug as you suggest.  I thought I tried a new project before.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the raster you are trying to add has NULL or No Data values represented by # in some of the pixels. I had the same problem and solved by replacing NULL values with 0.

Comment: I'm not sure how to check that other than a clicking around.  I have -9999 for the No-Data value which I can see from 'layer info' in the General tab